# Dojo Select widget validation style

Tags: select, widget, dojo

Many dojo form widgets, like DateTextBox will style themselves in red (claro theme) with an "!" to indicate that the field isn't valid after focus. I can't seem to get this type of styling to work with the Select widget. I have the value set to required, but if the user leaves it in the default state, blank, then it remains unstyled.

I tried to test this programmatically:

```
wigs = dijit.findWidgets(node);
for( i = 0; i < wigs.length; i++ ) {
    wigs[i].focus();
}
```

This triggers validation on several other widgets and they are styled appropriately, but not he Select widgets. Anyone know how to make it obvious that those select widgets are not validating?

Oh, and wigs[i].isValid() is definitely false for those select widgets.

Answer (score 0):

The styles used by FilteringSelect in these circumstances still use the error styles from ValidationTextBox; this isn't the case for Select, and it looks as if there are no styles for `.dijitSelectError` in any of the themes.  I'm thinking Select may not have initially supported any validation so that might be why.

So you'd have to add your own styles for this to work.  Also note that there is no node with the `dijitValidationIcon` class in Select's template, which is what's responsible for the '!' in those other widgets.